# Angular page cannot scroll on ng-bind-html with long content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this controller.

```
angular.module('nkgen.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});
})
.controller('ContentController', function($scope, $stateParams, contentIndex, contentHtml) {
  var contentIndexData = {};
  var htmlcontent = {};

  contentIndexData = {
    id: $stateParams.contentId,
    name: $stateParams.contentName
  };

  $scope.content = contentIndexData;
  delete contentIndexData;

  $scope.htmlcontent = {body: 'Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>Loading...<br><br>'};
  delete htmlcontent;
})
```

And this is html template. (My current html template).

```
<ion-view view-title="{{content.name}}">
  <ion-content ng-bind-html="htmlcontent.body | sanitize" class="page-content-container padding-horizontal">
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

If I use...

```
<ion-view view-title="{{content.name}}">
  <ion-content class="page-content-container padding-horizontal">
    {{htmlcontent.body | sanitize}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

the page is working correctly. It can scroll but cannot render html.
- Scroll works only on Chrome but not others.

If I use my current html template, it can render html but cannot scroll.

How to make it scrollable on long content and also render html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try :

```
<span  ng-bind-html="htmlcontent.body | sanitize"></span>
```

Inside your ion-content ?

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. You need just another container element in your ion-content (not particularly a span)